NetSuite SuiteScript- How to set base price for a nonInventorySaleItem?
I have a basic NetSuite Restlet that I am using to create a nonInventoryItem and it works when calling it with Postman. I need to set the base price but am struggling to do so. This is my current working code.
define(['N/record', 'N/log'], function(record, log) {
function doPost(requestBody) {
    try {
        // Extract product details from the request body
        var itemName = requestBody.itemName;
        var itemDescription = requestBody.itemDescription;
        var itemPrice = parseFloat(requestBody.itemPrice); // Ensure it's a number
        var incomeAccount = requestBody.incomeAccount;
        var expenseAccount = requestBody.expenseAccount;
        var taxable = requestBody.taxable;
        var taxItemCode = 2; // default is taxable

        log.debug({
            title: 'Item: ' + itemName,
            details: 'Description: ' + itemDescription + ', expenseAccount: ' + expenseAccount + ', itemPrice: ' + itemPrice
        });

        if(taxable == "False"){
          taxItemCode = 1;
        }

        // Create a new inventory item record
        var itemRecord = record.create({
            type: record.Type.NON_INVENTORY_ITEM,
            isDynamic: true
        });
        
        // Set item fields
        itemRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'itemid',
            value: itemName
        });
        itemRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'displayname',
            value: itemName
        });
        itemRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'subtype',
            value: 'Sale'
        })
        itemRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'salesdescription',
            value: itemDescription
        });
       
       itemRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'taxschedule',
            value: taxItemCode
        });
        itemRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'incomeaccount',
            value: incomeAccount
        });            
        itemRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'expenseaccount',
            value: expenseAccount
        });
        itemRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'costestimatetype',
            value: 'ITEMDEFINED'
        });

        
        //Set the Include Children checkbox for subsidiaries
        itemRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'includechildren',
            value: true
        });
                   
       
        // Save the item record
        var itemId = itemRecord.save();

        log.debug({
            title: 'Item Created',
            details: 'Item ID: ' + itemId
        });

        return {
            success: true,
            message: 'Item created successfully.',
            itemId: itemId
        };
    } catch (e) {
        log.error({
            title: 'Error Creating Item',
            details: e.message
        });

        return {
            success: false,
            message: 'Error creating item.',
            error: e.message
        };
    }
}

return {
    post: doPost
};

});
Not finding the answer in the API docs, I asked ChatGPT and Claude several times and tried several different suggestions but no luck. I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction. I'm not a NetSuite expert at all and appreciate any help.
What I really want is to set the field like the $130 in this image:


I never could get this to work, so I took another approach: Create the item with the restlet code without the price, then do an update to set the price.
Using a simple PATCH using the REST API, I can use it like this:
Calling https://-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/noninventorysaleitem/
Body data:
{
  "price": {       
        "items": [
            {                
                "price": 99.99,
                "priceLevel": {                    
                    "id": "1"                    
                },
                "priceLevelName": "Base Price",
                "quantity": {
                    "value": "0"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

